# How to deserialize bigdecimal in hazelcast using IdentifiedDataSerializable

Tags: xml, hazelcast

I am using IdentifiedDataSerializable to serialize an object in HazelCast. Problem is when i am trying to deserialize BigDecimal I am getting exception:

> com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There
>   is no suitable de-serializer for type -6144.

```
public class TransactionSerializableFactory  implements DataSerializableFactory{
    public static final int FACTORY_ID = 1;

    public static final int TRANSACTION_TYPE = 1;

    public IdentifiedDataSerializable create(int typeId) {
        if ( typeId == TRANSACTION_TYPE ) { 
            return new CoreTransaction();
          } else {
            return null; 
          }
    }

}
```

I have registered this in Serialzation in xml. Can someone help me solving this

Comment: Please show the write / read code. I would guess that those methods are async, meaning that you have written data in a different form or order than you try to read it.

Comment: i am writing data into one node. n i am reading data from that node through client configuration..this works fine both server and client are in same instance

Comment: I am using writeObject to write the BigDecimal and readObject to read the Bigdecimal

Comment: It is not about BigDecimal itself, it also depends on the data read / written around it.

Comment: no..if iam avoiding serializing and deserializing of bigdecimal data every thing is working fine..only if bigdecimal is involved it is giving a problem

Comment: Is it the last value in the class you're trying to deserialize? It would be easier if you could just share the code (serialize and deserialize methods), otherwise we're going from one guess to another forever. If you prefer you can also mail the code privately if public sharing is not possible.

Comment: yes.its working if i move the BigDecimal to top..wat is the reason for this behaviour

Comment: I wuld still say, async read/write methods, therefore you're at the wrong byte position when reading the BigDecimal which means the deserializer cannot figure out the type (the reason for the weird classtype id)

Comment: Problem is because i am using out.write('y') instead of out.writeChar('y') to serialize char..after i changed it out.writeChar() it is working

Comment: Glad it is resolved!